# New relic integration with go : I am unable to monitor my go project with new relic

Tags: go, newrelic, newrelic-platform, go-agent

**I am unable to monitor my go project with the new relic**

**I am able to monitor using JAVA**

I have follows the documentation steps: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/go-agent/installation/install-new-relic-go/

1. **From [github.com/newrelic/go-agent](https://github.com/newrelic/go-agent), use your preferred process; for example:**
   bash command `go get github.com/newrelic/go-agent/v3/newrelic`
2. **Import the github.com/newrelic/go-agent/v3/newrelic package in your application.**
     `import github.com/newrelic/go-agent/v3/newrelic`
3. **Initialize the Go agent by adding the following in the main function or in an init block:**

   ```
   app, err := newrelic.NewApplication(
       newrelic.ConfigAppName("Your Application Name"),
       newrelic.ConfigLicense("YOUR_NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY")
   )
   ```

**NOTE: I have follows all the trouble shooting as well.**

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/newrelic/go-agent/v3/newrelic"
)

var newrelicApp *newrelic.Application

func main() {
    app, err := newrelic.NewApplication(
        newrelic.ConfigAppName("MyAppMain"),
        newrelic.ConfigLicense("<YOUR_NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY>"),
        newrelic.ConfigAppLogForwardingEnabled(true),
    )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error is " + err.Error())
    } else {
        newrelicApp = app
        http.HandleFunc(newrelic.WrapHandleFunc(app, "/test", customEvent))
    }
}

func customEvent(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "recording a custom event")

    newrelicApp.RecordCustomEvent("MyAppMainEvent", map[string]interface{}{
        "text":      "Hello VP",
        "env":       "go_local",
        "alertType": "error",
        "priority":  "Critical",
        "source":    "MyAppMain",
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to store the app in a global variable and override the existing one, this will cause issues, and also you need to start a web server.
i updated the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/newrelic/go-agent/v3/newrelic"
)

func main() {
    app, err := newrelic.NewApplication(
        newrelic.ConfigAppName("MyAppMain"),
        newrelic.ConfigLicense("280d644a5b4fc4859d5fa75b8897f4422bb5NRAL"),
        newrelic.ConfigAppLogForwardingEnabled(true),
    )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error is " + err.Error())
    } else {

        http.HandleFunc(newrelic.WrapHandleFunc(app, "/test", customEvent))
    }

    http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)

}

func customEvent(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    txn := newrelic.FromContext(req.Context())
    io.WriteString(w, "recording a custom event")

    txn.Application().RecordCustomEvent("MyAppMainEvent", 
    map[string]interface{}{
        "text":      "Hello VP",
        "env":       "go_local",
        "alertType": "error",
        "priority":  "Critical",
        "source":    "MyAppMain",
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.
It still not working.
In my new relic dashboard "MyAppMain" App is not showing.
Steps follows :
1. create new main.go file 
2. added above code
3. run the go proj with terminal "go run main.go" in VS Code

Comment: it's not gonna work, you need to start a server and after that invoke the /test endpoint.
add `http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)` at the end of your main and after running "go run main.go" do a curl to invoke the endpoint "curl 127.0.01:8090/test"

Comment: What I need to do if I want to hit directly while I do"go run main.go"?

Comment: http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil) this code will working for me so my app is created but custom events are not created.